# onActivityReenter lifecycle method for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, shared-element-transition

I wanna get notified when my Fragment reenters before a shared element transition happens, like I can do with the Activities `onActivityReenter` method. Is there a similar way I can do this for fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no `onActivityReenter` method in `Fragment`, what I've found myself doing is calling a public method on my `Fragment` from the `Activity`.

Define a public method in your `Fragment` class:

```
public void onReenter(Intent data) {
   // Do whatever with the data here
}
```

Then just call it when `onActivityReenter` is called in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data);
    ItemFragment fragment = (ItemFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ITEM_TAG);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onReenter(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work when the fragment transition is performed in the same Activity.

Comment: @Moritz Could you elaborate on that at all, please?